# Pass a reference/pointer to a method called with NSTimer?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have a timer calling a method that needs to have two references to other variables (gravity and player)

```
func update(inout gravity: CGVector, inout player: Player) {  
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("myMethod"), userInfo: gravity, repeats: true) // Here I get the error: extra argument 'selector' in call
    }

func myMethod() {  
    println(timer.userInfo.gravity.dx)
}
```

While the above works for contants or regular variables, when I try to pass a pointer or an inout variable I get the error "Extra argument 'selector' in call". How can I pass the references to the variables to myMethod?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  Does `func myMethod(NSTimer *timer)` fix it?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't fix it. When I change useInfo from "nil" to "gravity" I get the error "extra argument 'selector' in call" also I need to pass a reference to the other variable too, and I'm not sure how to pass two arguments to userInfo.

Comment: Why are you using UnsafePointer instead of [inout parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267)?

Comment: I didn't know they existed. I just tried implementing them but I keep getting the error "Extra argument 'selector' in call" when changing nil to any variable

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the Selector:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "myMethod", userInfo: gravity, repeats: true)
```

This is the format that works for me.  Also, in my tests, if you pass `gravity` as `userInfo`, and `gravity` as a `memory` property, you can access it like this:

```
func myMethod() {  
    println(timer.userInfo.memory)
}
```

Comment: Hi @undetected, how can I pass a second argument like this? I need to pass the variable player too

Comment: I tried this and it works if I pass a let or var, but I get an error when trying with any kind of reference

Comment: The way I've been able to do it is declare a class to hold the user info.  I've tried using a tuple, but I end up with the same error you got in the original question.